# iPhone: Create a reusable component (control) that has some Interface Builder pieces and some code

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I want to create a reusable component (a custom control) for the iPhone.  It consists of several standard controls prearranged on a View, and then some associated code.  My goals are:

1. I want to be able to use Interface Builder to lay out the subviews in my custom control;
2. I want to somehow package the whole thing up so that I can then fairly easily drag and drop the resulting custom component into other Views, without having to manually rewire a bunch of outlets and so on.  (A little manual rewiring is fine, I just don't want to do tons and tons of it.)

Let me be more concrete, and tell you specifically what my control is supposed to do.  In my app, I sometimes need to hit a web service to validate data that the user has entered.  While waiting for a reply from the web service, I want to display a spinner (an activity indicator).  If the web services replies with a success code, I want to display a "success" checkmark.  If the web service replies with an error code, I want to display an error icon and an error message.

The single-use way to do this is pretty easy: I just create a UIView that contains a UIActivityIndicatorView, two UIImages (one for the success icon and one for the error icon), and a UILabel for the error message.  Here's a screenshot, with the relevant parts marked in red:

[image]

I then wire up the pieces to outlets, and I put some code in my controller.

But how do I package up those pieces -- the code and the little collection of views -- so that I can reuse them?  Here are a few things I found that get me partway there, but aren't that great:

- I can drag the collection of views and controls into the Custom Objects section of the Library; then, later, I can drag them back out onto other views.  But (a) it forgets which images were associated with the two UIImages, (b) there is a lot of manual rewiring of four or five outlets, and (c) most importantly, this doesn't do bring along the code.  (Perhaps there's an easy way to wire up the code?)
- I think I could create an IBPlugin; not sure if that would help, and it seems like a lot of work, and also it's not entirely clear to me whether IBPlugins work for iPhone development.
- I thought, "Hmm, there's code associated with this -- that smells like a controller," so I tried creating a custom controller (e.g. `WebServiceValidatorController`) with associated XIB file.  That actually feels really promising, but then at that point I can't figure out how, in Interface Builder, to drag this component onto other views.  The `WebServiceValidatorController` is a controller, not a view, so I can drag it into a Document Window, but not into a view.

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: I have found this link to provide some good information: http://www.bartlettpublishing.com/site/bartpub/blog/3/entry/327

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've created similar constructs except that I do not use the result in IB, but instantiate using the code. I'll describe how that works, and at the end I'll give you a hint how that can be used to accomplish what you're after.

I start from an empty XIB file where I add one custom view at the top level. I configure that custom view to be my class. Below in view hierarchy I create and configure subviews as required.

I create all IBOutlets in my custom-view class, and connect them there. In this exercise I ignore the "File's owner" completely.

Now, when I need to create the view (usually in controller as part of while/for-loop to create as much of them as needed), I use NSBundle's functionality like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect fooBarViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, FOOBARVIEW_HEIGHT);
    for (MBSomeData *data in self.dataArray) {
        FooBarView *fooBarView = [self loadFooBarViewForData:data];
        fooBarView.frame = fooBarViewFrame;
        [self.view addSubview:fooBarView];

        fooBarViewFrame = CGRectOffset(fooBarViewFrame, 0, FOOBARVIEW_HEIGHT);
    }
}

- (FooBarView*)loadFooBarViewForData:(MBSomeData*)data
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooBarView" owner:self options:nil];
    FooBarView *fooBarView = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    fooBarView.barView.amountInEuro = data.amountInEuro;
    fooBarView.barView.gradientStartColor = data.color1;
    fooBarView.barView.gradientMidColor = data.color2;
    fooBarView.titleLabel.text = data.name;
    fooBarView.titleLabel.textColor = data.nameColor;
    return fooBarView;
}
```

Notice, how I set owner of nib to `self` - there's no harm as I didn't connect "File's owner" to anything. The only valuable result from loading this nib is its first element - my view.

If you want to adapt this approach for creating views in IB, it's pretty easy. Implement loading of subview in a main custom view. Set the subview's frame to main view's bounds, so that they are the same size. The main view will become the container for your real custom view, and also an interface for external code - you open only needed properties of its subviews, the rest is encapsulated. Then you just drop custom view in IB, configure it to be your class, and use it as usual.

Comment: You should not depend on the order of the objects returned from loadNibNamed:owner:options:, instead, you should check the class / tag values on the objects returned.    One advantage of using the File's Owner and outlets as I outlined in my answer is that you don't need to loop through the objects returned from this method.

Comment: well, I'm using the fact that I added only one top-level object to the XIB - and because there is only one, it is pretty safe not to iterate but pickup the first one.

Comment: Good functional solution, I still wish there was some way to reuse pre-laid out objects in IB

Comment: guys is the FooBarView inherits from UIView or UIViewController, I'm pretty new to this ?

Comment: It Inherits from UIView :) sorry for the late answer :)

Answer (score 21):

Here is how I'm solving a similar problem: I wanted to:

- create reusable, self-contained "widget module classes" implementing a complex view built from multiple UIKit components (and other nested widget module classes!).  The higher-level customer classes of these widget classes don't care about what's a UILabel, what's a UIImageView internally within the widget, the customer classes only care about concepts like "displaying the score" or "showing the team logo."
- within a widget module class, lay out the UI for the widget and hookup outlets using interface builder
- for higher level customers of a widget, I wanted to be able to place the frame of the widget within the view of the customer in interface builder without having to design custom plugins to IB, etc.

These widgets are not top level controllers: so it makes no sense for them to be subclasses of UIViewController.  Then also there's the Apple advice not to have more than one VC on a visible screen at a time.    Also, there's so much advice and opinion floating around like "MVC!  MVC!   You must separate your View and your control!   MVC!" that people are so strongly discouraged from subclassing UIView or ever placing app logic within a UIView subclass.

But I decided to do it anyway (subclass UIView).   I've been around the block a few times (but fairly new still to the iPhone SDK/UIKit), and I'm very sensitive to design that is ugly, and that can cause problems, and I frankly don't see the problem with subclassing UIView and adding outlets and actions.   In fact there are many advantages to making your reusable widget be a subclass of UIView rather than be UIViewController-based:

- You can place a direct instance of the widget class in a customer view's interface builder layout, and the widget view's UIView frame will be properly initialized when the customer class is loaded from the xib.  This is much cleaner to me than putting a "placeholder view" in the customer, then instantiating the widget module programmatically, and setting the widget's frame to that of the placeholder, and then swapping the placeholder view for the widget's view.
- You can create a clean and simple xib file to lay out the widget's components in interface builder.  The File's Owner is set to your widget class.   The nib file contains a root (vanilla) UIView where all of the GUI is laid out, and then in the awakeFromNib: method of the widget, this nib view is added to the widget itself as a subview.   Any frame size adjustments can be handled here, entirely within the widget code, if any is necessary.  Like so:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyWidgetView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];
}
```

- The widget self-initialzes its user interface by using NSBundle's loadNibNamed:owner:options method in its own awakeFromNib method, so integration of the widget into customer classes is clean: just drop a UIView into the customer's view in IB, change the UIView's class to MyWidgetView, and in the customer's init or viewDidLoad set up any defaults in the widget's display using the widget's API that you write yourself (setScore:  setTeamImage: etc.)

It seems to me there is essentially no difference in the resulting code between subclassing a UIView in this way to make a reusable "widget", and using a UIViewController.  In both cases the .h files contain widget class members, outlets, action declarations, and special API declarations.   In both cases the .m file contains action implementations, and special API implementation.   And the view IS separated from the control -- the view is in the xib file!

So, in summary, this is what I do for packaging up complex reusable view widgets:

- Make the widget class a subclass of UIView
- Instantiate the widget wherever you want, in other views in your app in IB directly by dragging a UIView from the tools library, and changing the class to your "MyWidgetClass."
- Design your widget's UI in IB in a nib inside a root vanilla UIView.
- in the widget class's awakeFromNib: method, load the widget's UI from xib and do 
  `[self addSubview:self.theXibRootView]`
- Code the widget just like you would a UIViewController: outlets, actions, special APIs

I'd be interested in hearing about other structural systems for creating reusable widgets, and what the advantages are over this approach.

If the widget needs to report events to the customer class, just use a delegate protocol where the customer sets the widget's delegate to self, just like in a UIViewController.