# Reusable Date Picker using Interface Builder Possible?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, interface-builder, xcode4.2

My question is similar to [iPhone: Create a reusable component (control) that has some Interface Builder pieces and some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036398/iphone-create-a-reusable-component-control-that-has-some-interface-builder-pi) but it doesn't quite solve my problem.  Also, it is a year later now and who knows what has changed in the meantime.

I'm developing an iPad app using Interface Builder and a storyboard.  I need the same date picker popover in a couple of places but I haven't been able to figure out how to reuse the same component from different views.  I have spent a couple of hours on this, trying things out, reading docs, googling and stackoverflowing.

Currently I've have done a hack job that gets me the functionality but it isn't pretty.  What has been the most promising approach so far is to have a popover segue from a button to a new UIViewController which contains the date picker and some other widgets.  This shows the date picker popover when pressing the button and also animates the date picker away when pressing outside of it.

However, I can't figure out how to use this from multiple buttons.  I have tried delegates but I'm screwing up somewhere.

Comment: I ran into the same challenge and implemented a reusable set of controls that use Block call backs instead of a protocol.  This makes it very flexible and useful when you want to use the same control components in several different places with varying use cases.

The sample project and framework is available here:https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/BDApplicationHelpers.  

It doesn't implement storyboarding, but maybe it will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a view controller that has a datepicker in its view. Let's name this `DatePickerViewController`. This class can implement a protocol, like `datePickerViewController:pickedDate:` or something like that. When a date is picked using this date picker, it can inform its delegate about the picked date.

And then, whenever you need to present this date picker from a button, you can create a new `UIPopoverController`, create a new `DatePickerViewController` instance, give this instance to the popover as its `contentViewController` and present the popover controller from your button.

To get information about the picked date, when you're creating the `DatePickerViewController`, you can set your presenting view controller the `delegate` of it, so you can know about the picked dates.