# Load a dozen UIView of the same type from a NIB

Tags: ios, performance, uiview, xib, nib

this might be a dumb question but I found nothing to it...
I stumbled over a piece of code that I think can be optimized.

I have a viewcontroller that consists of 24 notes/postits. 
the following gets called during the view-did-load-process:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostitView" owner:self options:nil];
    for (UIView *subview in nib)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"PostitView")]) 
        {
```

it takes quite a while to load the postit again and again from the nib.

I would have said, I simply make a copy from the subview, but it wont work. so whats the right way then?

thanks!!!
Tom

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036398/iphone-create-a-reusable-component-control-that-has-some-interface-builder-pi/4037281#4037281

Comment: there is no difference to what I am doing. Apparently this is not possible when using NIB's.

Comment: how long time does it take to load your view?

Comment: well it takes too long(in my and the performance profiler opinion). its just alright if I must do it just once. but I am planning to extend this viewcontroller, so these loadFromNibview could happen quite frequently

Comment: did you try to add it to a new xib which has only PostitView then you don't have to loop through all views,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the loop, create a `UINib` object representing your nib.  Inside the loop, ask the `UINib` to instantiate itself.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PostitView" bundle:nil];
Class viewClass = [PostitView class];
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    for (UIView *subview in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:viewClass)  {
            ...
```

Comment: instantiateWithOwner ...well this is what I was looking for. thanks mate!